# error while downloading adt plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

while downloading `adt plugin for eclipse classic ( win 7)` i get following error :

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.M20100909-0800 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.6.1.M20100909-0800)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Traceview 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.M20100909-0800 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.6.1.M20100909-0800)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.1.M20100826-1330]
```

Comment: maybe better to migrate the question to http://superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

From your log
'Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.M20100909-0800 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.6.1.M20100909-0800) Only one of the following can be installed at once: Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330'

Reinstall Eclipes to Eclipse Classic 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your eclipse and android sdk tool

Answer (score 0):

It's a bunch of errors and I had similar problems. I focussed on this one:

> Only one of the following can be installed at once:

So step back to the dialog where to select the packages you want to download and select only one of the packages listed in the error message. It's a trial and error thing.

Anyway reading this:

> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_blablahblah

I might gave v3.6.1 a try first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your install went wrong, but I do know the proper way of installing Eclipse and the ADT Plugin.

First, you need to install the ADT Plugin on your computer:

1. Download and install Android SDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
2. Start the Android SDK and AVD Manager (file directory tools/android).
3. Choose the API level you'd like to develop for (Android 4.0.3 (API 15) is the newest version. However, most phones work with Android 2.1 (API 7), if I'm not mistaken. If you'd like to develop for your own phone, also tick the box for your API level).
4. Preferably, the "Samples", "Google APIs" and "Sources for Android SDK" can be unchecked.
5. Click "Install packages".

Now you need to install some Developer Tools in Eclipse. I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, but I'm quite sure that it works the same way for Eclipse Classic:

1. Start Eclipse and choose "Help" > "Install new software".
2. Click "Add" and insert the following:

> Name: ADT Plugin ----- Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
>
> When done loading, check "Developer Tools" and click "Next".
>
> Again, click "Next", accept the terms & conditions and choose "Finish".
>
> Wait for Eclipse to complete the install, and then restart the program.
>
> Eclipse may have already tracked your Android SDK Location. If it has not:

1. In Eclipse, go to "Window" > "Preferences".
2. Click "Android".
3. In "SDK Location", insert the path to your "android-sdk" directory.

I hope this helps.